# ImportError: No module named 'numpy' while installing scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, pip, scikit-learn

I am trying to test scikit-learn library, but didn't manage to install it.

More details : I did install numpy, scipy, matplotlib and I can use them just fine. However, when I use `pip` (`pip install -U scikit-learn`), I get this error :

```
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\...\scikit-learn\setup.py", setup_package()
    File "C:\Users\...\scikit-learn\setup.py", from numpy.distutils.core import setup
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I couldn't find anything about this.

I tried installing scikit-learn directly by using `python setup.py` and had the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS do you have?

Comment: I'm using Windows seven

Comment: Which version of Python and which version of NumPy do you running?

Comment: Python 2.7.10 and NumPy 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are something wrong with the installation of numpy.
Try download and reinstall following package (for Python 2.7):

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/numpy/NumPy/1.9.2/numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe?r=&ts=1442420256&use_mirror=netix